# Delayed script to boot exagear and skype using RPI3 on debian

Tags: startup, sysvinit, architecture, skype, delay

I'm using Exagear desktop to run Skype on RPI3 (Raspbian/Debian). I have some naive users also using the system because of which I want to load both of them on boot (maybe delayed startup service).

I understand how to [create a script](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-automatically-start-program-on-boot-in-debian.html) to be run on startup and also possibly [delay it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110434/how-to-make-some-initscript-start-after-delay-at-boot) so the dependencies are completely loaded but I don't know how to script to have skype startup withing exagear in the same startup script.

Right now what I do to luanch them is to use the GUI shortcut to run exagear -> it opens a terminal -> I verify 'arch' has switched over from arm to x86-> run 'skype'.

I would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

To run x86 app from ARM terminal use the following command: 'exagear -- /usr/bin/skype'

The last part is the path to your x86 app binary inside the guest x86 system. You can find it if you type 'which skype' in x86 terminal.